# Protractor - Expected: +Nan but Actual: 5

Tags: protractor, cucumber

I am using Protractor and cucumber:

I have this in Test.ts

```
async getElements(): Promise<number> {
    let allElements: number;

    await element.all(by.id('test')).count().then(total => {
        allElements = total;
    });

    return allElements;
}
```

Then in steps.ts

```
let totalBefore: number;
let totalAfter: number;

Then('the entry is removed from the list', async () => {
    totalAfter = await Test.getElements();
    expect(+totalAfter).to.be.lessThan(+totalBefore);
})
```

I receive this error

```
AssertionError
       + expected - actual

       -5
       +NaN
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Is totalBefore assigned a value anywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `getElements()` always return `undefined`, then `+totalAfter` becomes to `+undefined`, and Javascript return `NaN`.

Try change `getElements()` as following:

```
async getElements(): Promise<number> {
    return await element.all(by.id('test')).count();
}
```

Comment: can you `console.log(totalAfter)` and `console.log(totalBefore)` before assertion in your code.